# jQuery match height isn't fast enough

Tags: jquery, height, match

http://www.tigerstudiodesign.com/blog/

sometimes the match height isn't fast enough, especially when you click a link to go to another page. the heights wont match each other unless I refresh.

code I use to match heights:

```
function matchColHeights(col1, col2) {
  $('img').load(function() { //let images load before I get the height, else height is calculated based on text alone
     var col1Height = $(col1).height();
     //alert('col1: '+col1Height);
       var col2Height = $(col2).height();
       //alert('col2: '+col2Height);
       if (col1Height < col2Height) {
       $(col1).height(col2Height);
       } else {
        $(col2).height(col1Height);
       }
     });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    matchColHeights('#leftPanel', '#rightPanel');
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What code is not working?

Comment: the heights simply don't match fast enough. it works fine, it's just at times the #leftPanel and #rightPanel don't match heights because browser can't keep up or something?

Comment: Well, then just use CSS style visibility:hidden on both or on their container, and remove or switch to "visible" only once is done.

Comment: how would that help match heights? that makes no sense unless I am not understanding what you are saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this plugin before for matching height on columns quickly. http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/